# Searching and replacing a line in linux?

Tags: linux, perl, sed, grep

How can I find and replace every instance of a {% extends "a/b/c/d" %} with another {% extends "e/f/g/h" %} in every file in a directory?  Also, if anything comes after the statement on the same line I would like to keep it.

I've looked over using perl like the following:

```
perl -pi -e 's/find/replace/g' *.html
```

But I don't know perl and don't know the best way to go about escaping all of the characters in my find/replace strings (ie {. /, ", etc).

Any easier solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use some character other than `/` in perl's `s/find/replace/g` syntax 
so you don't have to escape all the forward slashes in `a/b/c/d`:

```
perl -pi -e 's|{% extends "a/b/c/d" %}|{% extends "e/f/g/h" %}|g' *.html
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e 's/{% extends "\/a\/b\/c\/d"/{% extends "\/e\/f\/g\/h/g"' *.html
```

or

```
sed -i -e 's|{% extends "a/b/c/d"|{% extends "e/f/g/h"|g' *.html
```